# Reading consecutive bytes as one integer

Tags: c++, binary

I am new here, and would like to ask this question. 
I am working with a binary file that each byte, multiple bytes or even parts of a byte have a different meaning.

What I have been trying so far is to read a number of bytes (4 in my example) as a one block.

I have them in Hexadecimal representation like: `00 1D FB C8`.

Using the following code, I read them separately:

```
for (int j = 36; j < 40;j++)
    {
         cout << dec << (bitset<8>(fileBuf[j])).to_ulong();         
    }
```

where `j` is the position of the byte in the file. The previous code gives me `029251200` which is wrong. What I want is read the 4 bytes at once and get the answer of `1965000`

I appreciate any help. 
Thank you.

Comment: What is `fileBuf`?

Comment: `fileBuf` is a pointer I use it to read the binary file

Comment: That is, how do you have fileBuf defined. Is it char[4]? If it is int[4\] are you asking how to convert?, is it the result of a scanf()?

Comment: Bad news, man. This: `cout << dec << (bitset<8>(fileBuf[j])).to_ulong();` isn't reading jack.

Comment: If you used scanf to read from a file into the buffer, then just set the format correctly.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Show us what you tried using both methods and what result you got. Then show us what you expect to get.

Comment: What endian is your data protocol using?

Comment: @sabbahillel I defined fileBuf as `BYTE *fileBuf;`

Comment: It appears that you must have read a binary file into the buffer. If that is the case and you have defined fileBuf as `char fileBuf[4]` cast it into an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DWORD final = (fileBuf[j] << 24) + (fileBuf[j+1] << 16) + (fileBuf[j+2] << 8) + (fileBuf[j+3]);
```

Also depends what kind of endian you want (ABCD / DCBA / CDAB)

EDIT (cant reply due to low rep, just joined today)

> I tried to extend the bitset, however it gave the value of the first byte only

It will not work because the fileBuf is 99% byte array, extending from 8bit to 32bit(int) wont make any difference because its still a byte array which is 8bit. You have to mathematicly calculate the value from 4 array elements into original integer representation. see code above edit

Comment: Yes!!! Confuse the OP with the shift operators the hard way. +1 for mentioning endianess.

Comment: there is nothing to confuse. people should learn basic operations before even using standard libraries. you dont read the book from end or do you? :)

Comment: Thank you @TNTworks your solution worked. Honestly I didn't know exactly what the code does in the background, and I also don't know what is endian. Will search about it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer isnt "Wrong" this is a logic error. Youre not storing the values and adding the computation

C8 is 200 in decimal form, so youre not appending the value to the original subset.

The answer it spit it out, was infact what you programmed it to do.

You need to either extend the bitset to a larger amount to append the other hex numbers or provide some other means of outputting

Comment: I tried to extend the bitset, however it gave the value of the first byte only

Comment: Yeah its tricky, TNTWorks as the right solution. Its a difference of

 a = 1 + 2 + 5 + 6
vs
a = 1256

Which his solution provides the correct notation for shifting the bits in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the format of the function from the question, you could do:

```
    //little-endian
{
        int i = (fileBuf[j]<<0) | (fileBuf[j+1]<<8) | (fileBuf[j+2]<<16) | (fileBuf[j+3]<<24);
        cout << dec << i;
}

    // big-endian
{
        int i = (fileBuf[j+3]<<0) | (fileBuf[j+2]<<8) | (fileBuf[j+1]<<16) | (fileBuf[j]<<24);
        cout << dec << i;
}
```